# How to send date from one view to another in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I want to make the program where you have to enter some data, and then it will manipulate that data and show it on the other view when you click done. I search through multiple tutorials, but still cant understand how you do that. I have a textfield - lesson1 and want to pass it to the label in the second view. The views are called EditClasses and DayView. Thanks a lot.

Also I need to change the data every 24 hours, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple way to pass information from one view to another, and in general, to store information and use it in other views is to use NSUserDefaults. You can store objects like NSString or NSNumber and others in a place reserved for your app while it's running.

Save your information when leaving the first view:

```
NSUserDefaults *infoSaved = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[infoSaved setObject:@"Sample Text" forKey:@"LabelTitle"];
[infoSaved synchronize];
```

Make sure to call synchronize after setting objects. And extract them at the loading of your second view controller:

```
NSUserDefaults *infoSaved = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *infoFromUserDefaults = [infoSaved objectForKey:@"LabelTitle"];
[MyLabel setTitle:infoFromUserDefaults];
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it still doesnt work, only shows me a blank label.